# Clear interval and variables: clearinterval fails

Tags: javascript, variables, setinterval

I have this code: It's very simple. I create an interval, and that works fine, but when I clear it, that statement is the only thing that fails.

clearinterval(interval);

This line fails, dragging don the whole function with it. If I comment out this one line, discomodeoff() works perfectly, besides that my interval is still running.

```
var interval;
function discomodeon() {
    interval = setInterval( 'flashtext()', 50 );
    document.body.style.background = "#000000";
    discoball.style.visibility="visible";
    on.style.display="none";
    off.style.display="block";
    music.innerHTML = "<embed src='discomusic.mp3' autostart='true' loop='true' hidden='true'></embed>";
}
function discomodeoff() {
    clearinterval(interval);
    document.body.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
    discoball.style.visibility="hidden";
    on.style.display="block";
    off.style.display="none";
    music.innerHTML = "";
}
```

I'm not sure why it fails, but it causes discomodeoff() to fail.

Comment: You will want to look at your javascript error log in the future; it would have told you what was wrong.

Comment: Where might I get one of these error logs?

Comment: ctrl-shift-J (and here are some more characters because comments must be at least 15 characters in length, and apparently @Stephen is now automatically removed from the comment due to either a bad StackOverflow feature so it wasn't being counted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `clearInterval`, not `clearinterval`.

```
function discomodeoff() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.body.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
    discoball.style.visibility="hidden";
    on.style.display="block";
    off.style.display="none";
    music.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Wow really? Capital I? Thanks a bunch :D

Comment: @Stephen: JavaScript is CaSe SeNsItIvE.  Be careful :-P